# DDD Using Specification pattern for Validation

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am thinking of using Specification pattern for validation purposes. The hard thing is how to tell the user why some Specification was not satisfied. What if the `Specification.IsSatisfiedBy()` will not only return a `bool` value, but also the reason of failure. It would look something like this:

```
interface ISpecification<T>
{
  CheckResult IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate);
}
```

where `CheckResult` is:

```
class CheckResult
{
  public bool IsSatisfied { get; }
  public string FailureReason { get; }
}
```

In [Fowler & Evans](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) work there is a concept of *Partially Satisfied Specification* whose purpose is to provide explanation what exactly was not satisfied. However in that document, it is implemented as additional method *remainderUnsatisfiedBy* which returns the Specification which was not accomplished by the *Candidate*.

So the question is: When using Specification for validation purposes, how to provide feedback to user that a given Specification was not satisfied? Is the solution I've presented above good?

Comment: First of all, are you really sure that Specification is the way to go? I mean, does each specification knows the context where a model might be or not valid? I can't say much since I don't know what the domain looks like. 

For some simple validation I think it's ok, but that's what DataAnnotation validation attributes are doing right now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Although you may use your Specifications classes for validation, I would suggest you keep them as separate concepts within your domain.  You may find that you need to re-use the same underlying specifications but need to return different "Failure Reasons" depending on purpose and context.  See [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20130117134221/http://codeinsanity.com/archive/2008/12/02/a-framework-for-validation-and-business-rules.aspx) for more details.

The author of the post referenced above has also kindly shared code to github and posted the code as NCommon.  Review these areas in particular:

**Specifications**:  https://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/tree/v1.2/NCommon/src/Specifications

**Validations**:  https://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/tree/v1.2/NCommon/src/Rules (especially the classes for **ValidationResult** and **ValidationError**)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I create Validation decorator for Specification (code is JAVA).

```
  interface Validator<T>{
    Respond validate(T t)
  }


  class abstract ValidationSpecificationDecorator<T> implements Validator<T> {
  Specification<T> spec;

  ValidationSpecificationDecorator(Specification<T> spec){
    this.spec =  spec;
  }

  public Respond  validate(T t) {
    Respond respond = new Respond();
    if(!spec.IsSatisfiedBy(t){
       respond.add(error(t));
    }
    return respond;
  )

  public abstract Error error(T t);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your language, but in Scala there is a concept (structure): Either[A,B]

And in calculations you either return right side (B) - for successful validation (object satisfy business rule) or left side (A) to express reason of failed validation for a given business object.

For the Specification purpose, you could return (for  `A` type) e.g. String (as an error message) or some objects/enums (or anything which is appropriate in your language) representing business reason of why specified object didn't satisfy the specification.

It's similar to your solution but more functional and robust.