# Domain Driven Design validation

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design

I am looking for a better and clean way to do validation in my domain entities.

Time ago I read a great article here at http://codeinsanity.com/archive/2008/12/02/a-framework-for-validation-and-business-rules.aspx

It is also referenced  here:

[DDD Using Specification pattern for Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655171/ddd-using-specification-pattern-for-validation)

The original article is not available anymore at the Web site.  Does someone have a copy of the article or could recommend me similar approaches?

Comment: Archived copy (latest): https://web.archive.org/web/http://codeinsanity.com/archive/2008/12/02/a-framework-for-validation-and-business-rules.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to just do your validation inside the CTOR and all methods that modify the state?